# How can I detect the Mouse Wheel for the WPF WebView control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, webview, mousewheel

I am trying to detect when the Mouse Wheel is being used on a WPF `WebView` control using the `PreviousMouseWheel` event.  In the xaml I tried adding the tag to the `WebView`, but the event only fires when the mouse is somewhere outside of the `WebView` control.  I also tried the tag on the containing Grid and the Window itself, but with the same result.

xaml:

```
<Grid Name="windowGrid">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="gridTest" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Controls:WebView Name="wvc" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                    Width="800" Height="600" 
                    Source="http://www.google.ca"
                    PreviewMouseWheel="my_PreviewMouseWheel"
             />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported. Generally bubbling routed events are used to trace state changes from `UI` elements. But if look at the sources on the [GitHub](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32) can be found only raising for one routed event - `new RoutedEventArgs(GotFocusEvent)`.

Comment: So not possible then.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current latest version of the `WebView2` _1.0.674-prerelease_ don't support `MouseWhell` events too. If is possible to download and run examples from  [https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples).